# admob layout integrate issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

I've got problem with integrate admob ad with my layout. In layout I have map fragment linear and relative layouts. I'd like that my ad by at the top or bottom of my app. My layout file looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxx" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/but" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/sback"
        android:hint="Wprowadź swój adres"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and when i choose graphical layout i've got this error:

```
   The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.android.gms.internal.cm
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
        at                    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace you are showing indicates that the AdView could not be created inside **the Eclipse editor**. What happens if you build and deploy to a device, does it work then?

I suspect your app works but your IDE is not setup correctly.